# How should I name and make foreign keys in Rails 5.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I'm just getting my start in developing in Rails so I thought I'd make an expense-tracking app for my family. As I'm sure will become obvious, I'm still wrapping my head around creating several database tables and having them all link together correctly. I've completed the Hartl rails tutorial but this is my first stab at making my own thing.

The core of the app is a collection of Expenses. Each Expense has an amount, a date, a reference to table of Vendors, and a reference to a table of ExpenseTypes. The problem is, I've generated an Expense through database seeds, but it doesn't refer to the entries in the other tables correctly:

This how I'm creating it, as the last entry in seeds.rb:

```
Expense.create!(amount: 500, date: Date.today, vendor_id: Vendor.first,  expensetype_id: ExpenseType.second, note: "This is the first expense!")
```

But when I go into the console to examine it:

```
2.3.4 :002 > Expense.first
Expense Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "expenses".* FROM "expenses" ORDER BY "expenses"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Expense id: 1, amount: 500, date: "2018-01-08", vendor_id: nil, expensetype_id: nil, note: "This is the first expense!", created_at: "2018-01-08 09:37:19", updated_at: "2018-01-08 09:37:19">
```

I suspect it's because the tables are a little awkwardly named, but I don't have enough experience to know what's going on for sure. I tried naming my classes in CamelCase and generating migrations through "rails generate migration", but I'm not sure what kind of replacing and searching it's doing based on underscores and pluralization in the table and class names.

Here's schema.rb:

```
  create_table "expense_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_expense_types_on_name"
  end

  create_table "expenses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "amount", null: false
    t.date "date"
    t.integer "vendor_id"
    t.integer "expensetype_id"
    t.string "note"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["expensetype_id"], name: "index_expenses_on_expensetype_id"
    t.index ["vendor_id"], name: "index_expenses_on_vendor_id"
  end

  create_table "vendors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_vendors_on_name"
  end
```

And here's the rest of seeds.db:

```
# Vendors
vendor_list = ["Vendor 1", "Vendor 2", "Vendor 3", "Vendor 4"]

vendor_list.each do |item|
  Vendor.create!(name: item)
end

#Expense types
expense_type_list = ["Daily groceries", "Eating out", "Travel", "Present"]

expense_type_list.each do |item|
  ExpenseType.create!(name: item)
end
```

And finally, expense.rb, which was automatically generated:

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :expensetype
end
```

Maybe that should be has_one? I tried changing it but there wasn't any difference. I'm a bit sheepish about generating migrations to change the Expense table since I don't want to fill up the folder with pointless or broken migrations and I'm still not very adept at using them.

Am I forgetting something significant? Is there a migration I can generate that will let everything hook into each other correctly? Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to update your `Expense` model:

```
class Expense < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :expense_type
end
```

As it should be `expense_type` not `expensetype` - you have to respect the model name.

Second, you are creating expense but you pass an object as id. If you are referencing to `vendor_id` then pass id, if to `vendor` then pass an object:

```
Expense.create!(amount: 500, date: Date.today, vendor: Vendor.first,  expense_type: ExpenseType.second, note: "This is the first expense!")
```

To sum up things, I found two problems:

1. You misspelled `ExpenseType` model name in association and in `Expense.create!`
2. You pass an object to `vendor_id` and `expense_type_id`

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! I changed the underscore in the Expense model and added the IDs to the create! statement:

`Expense.create!(amount: 500, date: Date.today, vendor_id: Vendor.first.id, expensetype_id: ExpenseType.second.id, note: "This is the first expense!")`

And now I'm getting integers which refer to their correct entries in the Vendor and ExpenseType tables. Is there an advantage to referring to them by their objects instead? In my very limited knowledge of SQL, I wonder if that's something that could be stored in a database table.

Comment: In database, you always store only reference to a given association, not whole object so there is no difference if you pass `id` or object instance in this case